# Piping commands in powershell to ssh not working

Tags: powershell, ssh

I'm trying to pipe commands to a host running a different OS via ssh. I need to send the commands as one string. Sending one at a time isn't an option. I can get this to work using quotes and newlines when I test on the ps cli. For example, sending 3 commands:

```
>Write-Output "Command1`nCommand2s`nCommand3`n" | ssh -tt user@host > out.txt
```

The out.txt file gets populated with my command output.

```
$ Command1
<output omitted>
$ Command2
<output omitted>
$ Command3
<output omitted>
```

When I try the same thing in ps script it doesn't work:

```
$cmds="`"Command1``nCommand2``nCommand3``n`""
Write-Output "commands to be sent:" $cmds
Write-Output $cmds | ssh -tt user@host > out.txt
```

The output I get shows that the string in $cmds is being formatted correctly as per the manual cli command:

```
commands to be sent:
"Command1`nCommand2`nCommand3`n"
```

But on my ssh host it's being interpreted as:

```
Error: command 'Command1`nCommand2`nCommand3`n' not recognized
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

By escaping the `$cmds` string as you have you are literally sending the " and ` and n characters to the remote system.  Did you try it as just:

```
$cmds="Command1`nCommand2`nCommand3`n"
```

This way the output from `Write-Output "stuff"` and `$cmds="stuff" ; Write-Output $cmds` would be the same.